# addEventListener sound on click

Tags: html, audio, canvas, html5-audio

What I want to do is an 'addEventListener' function. When the canvas is clicked and the raindrop appears, a sloshing sound is made. So no matter how many times you click, the sound will always play.

I had no idea what it was called and my professor suggested it. However, when I combed the google, all I find is button clicks or Jquery things. I don't want a button and I am not allowed to use Jquery.

As always, I only seek a push in the right direction.

Thanks for all the help you all have given me thus far.

```
var canvas;
var context;
var drops = [];
var squares = [];


function Drop(x,y,color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.dy = Math.random();
}


function Square(x,y,w,color){
    this.sx = x;
    this.sy = y;
    this.sw = w;
    this.color = color;
    this.qy = Math.random();
}

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    alert("Hello!\nClick on the screen for rain drops!");

    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);
    resizeCanvas();
    canvas.onclick = function(event){
        handleClick(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    };
    setInterval(handleClick,5);



}
function handleClick(x,y,w){
    var found = false;
    for(var i = 0; i<drops.length; i++){
        d = Math.sqrt((drops[i].x-x)*(drops[i].x-x) + (drops[i].y-y)*(drops[i].y-y));
        if(d<=5){
            drops.splice(i,1);
            found = true;
        }
}

    fillBackgroundColor();
    if(!found){
    var colors = ["#000080", "#add8e6", "blue"];
        var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        drops.push(new Drop(x,y,color));
        squares.push(new Square(x,y,w,color));

    }

            for(var i = 0; i<drops.length; i++){
        drawDrop(drops[i]);
}
                for(var i = 0; i<squares.length; i++){
        drawSquare(squares[i]);
}

}


function drawDrop(drop){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(drop.x, drop.y, 5, 0, Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = drop.color;
    context.moveTo(drop.x - 5, drop.y);
    context.lineTo(drop.x, drop.y - 7);
    context.lineTo(drop.x + 5, drop.y);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    if (drop.y + drop.dy > canvas.height || drop.y + drop.dy < 0)
        drop.dy != -drop.dy;
    drop.y += drop.dy;
};


function drawSquare(square){
    var sw = Math.floor(4);
    var sx = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    var sy = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(sx, sy, sw, sw); 
    context.fillStyle = '#add8e6';
    context.fill();

};




function fillBackgroundColor(){
    context.fillStyle = 'gray';
    context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
function resizeCanvas(){
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
    fillBackgroundColor();
    for(var i = 0; i<drops.length; i++){
        drawDrop(drops[i]);
    }

            for(var i = 0; i<squares.length; i++){
        drawSquare(squares[i]);
    }



}

function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
        return (degrees * Math.PI)/180;
    }
window.onload = init;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id='canvas' width=500 height=500></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Clicking a Canvas or any element**

To add an event listener to the canvas you just need the element, you can get it from the DOM in many ways, I have used `getElementById` and its unique id. Then to add a `click` event just attach a listener and the function to be called.

This will call playSound each time the canvas is clicked on.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasID"); // get the canvas
canvas.addEventListener("click",playSound);   // call playSound when clicked
// See below for the function playSound
```

You could also add event listeners for mousedown and mouseup as click is only called when the mouse button is released, which may not be the desired effect.

**Loading a sound**

As the sound needs to be loaded and that may take some time you need to have a way of indicating that the sound has loaded and is ready to play. For this simple answer a semaphore will do the trick. Just set a property to indicate loaded.

```
var sound = new Audio();         // create the audio
sound.src = "SoundFileURL.mp3";  // set the resource location 
sound.oncanplaythrough = function(){   // When the sound has completely loaded
    sound.readyToRock = true;    // flag sound is ready to play
                                 // I just made it up and can be anything
};
sound.onerror = function(){      // not required but if there are problems this will help debug the problem
    console.log("Sound file SoundFileURL.mp3 failed to load.")
};
```

**Repeated sound play**

The `playSound` function. An Audio resource can only be played as one sound. You can not play it over the top of itself. When repeatedly clicking you need to reset the sound playback position so it starts again. To do this just set the `currentTime` to 0 (the start of the sound) and call the method `play`. This way each click will start the sound or rewind and start again, no need to check if its playing. If you want the sound to overlap you need to load in several copies of it and cycle which one you play with each click.

```
// assuming sound is in scope from above code
function playSound(){
    if(sound && sound.readyToRock){  // check for the sound and if it has loaded
        sound.currentTime = 0;       // seek to the start
        sound.play();                // play it till it ends
    }
}
```

**Overlapping the sound**

Playing the same sound from an array so it overlaps. Load the same sound several times into an array. Keep a variable that will point to the next sound in the array to play when the user calls the function (via click event) then seek to the start and play the sound. Increment the next sound pointer ready for the next click.

This will have the sound play over itself. The number of times to load the sound will depend on how often the user clicks and how long the sound is. Don't go overboard as there is a point where you can't tell if a new sound has started or if a playing one has been restarted.

**Load same sound several times**

```
var sounds = [];  // array to hold the sound
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var sound = new Audio();         // create the audio
    sound.src = "SoundFileURL.mp3";  // set the resource location 
    sounds.push(sound);              // put the sound on the array
}
```

**Playing the array of sounds**

```
// assuming that the array sounds has the sounds you want to overlap
// and that they have been loaded so there is no need to check their status
var soundToPlay = 0; // the next sound to play

// the click event function.
function playSound(){
    var sound = sounds[soundToPlay % sounds.length]; // get the next sound
                                                     // making sure that it 
                                                     // does not go past the 
                                                     // of the array
    sound.currentTime = 0; // seek to start
    sound.play();          // play it
    soundToPlay += 1;      // point to the next sound to play
}
```

Comment: I understand how this code you provided me works. But I already have a handle click for the rain drops. Do I need to add them together in one large function? Are they able to work together like that?

Thank you for also taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @Blindman67 upped and marked nice answer, but I have a question about the `sound.src` portion. When I set the `src` I need to `sound.load()` before I `sound.play()`.  Does `sounds.push(sound);` take care of loading?

Comment: @JazzehPlatt You can have the click function do as much as you like. You can call the playSound function from the existing rain drop function, or if you like add a second event listener to the canvas click. Both ways will work fine.

Comment: @zer00ne You should not have to use `sound.load` as setting the src will begin the loading. It is important to know that when you set the src there is a delay before the sound has loaded and is ready to play. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio for all you need to know about the HTML Audio element

Comment: Just realized you helped me on my other question. Hello and thank you for your patience. I placed this code in a new canvas, but I'm not getting any sound on the click command. I even changed it to key stroke and nothing.

Comment: It may pay to listen to the `sound.error` event when loading the sound just to make sure the sound is loading. And of course the obvious, is the volume not down or muted on your device?

Comment: Oh so sorry I just saw an error in my code. its `.oncanplaythrough ` not `canPlayThrough` Will fix the answer now.. Again sorry about that.

Comment: Ok fixed it and added how to check for an error loading the sound file.

Comment: 6 years later and I passed my class and got this to work. I’m not sure if you’re still active but thank you again, the ADHD was completely wrong for not marking this answer as helpful.

Comment: I still keep an eye in here. Always good to hear that an answer has provided some assistance, especially years down the line, to live and learn (segways to).  I will point out that this answer should only be used for the most basic of audio needs. If you plan to play many sounds or overlap sounds (eg such as in a game) using [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) is many times more performant than using [HTMLAudioElement / Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext)